# Rails - how to find out if an ID is in the "has_many" relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, has-many

I have this structure of models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and in the view, I would need to find out if the respective user is in the specific group - how to do that?
Is there any native Rails method that would do something like this:

```
<% if current_user.groups.IS_THIS_GROUP_ID_IN_USERS_GROUPD(@group.id)? %>
```

or do I need to write it by me? Or, what's the most time efficient way to find out this?

**EDIT:**
Sorry guys, I made a mistake - there's one more model, so the structure look like this:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So what I am trying to do is basically this:

```
<% if current_user.favorites.IS_THIS_GROUP_ID_IN_USERS_FAVORITES_GROUPS(@group.id)? %>
```

I am sorry one more time, I don't know how I could overlooked the `Favorite` model.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would go with:

```
current.user.groups.include?(@group)
```

or if you only have an id:

```
current.user.group_ids.include?(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `current.user.groups.include?(@group)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class), which is done in the database.

```
current_user.groups.exists?(@group)
```

More information about `exists?` can be found in the [Rails Active Record Querying Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects).

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

If you're trying to see if the object has *any* groups, you may wish to use the [`.try` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) (although I'm not sure if this an accurate use case):

```
current_user.try(:groups)
```

--

**Include**

You may wish to try and use the [`include?` method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F), as shown by `spickerman`. This will ping the array to see if a particular element exists inside (it's not ActiveRecord, so you'll have to use `id`s)

```
current_user.groups.include?(@group.id) #-> true / false
```